# API Gateway for HTTP API failing in browser's preflight check with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway

I have configured my Lambda function with HTTP API for the API Gateway which is working fine with Postman. However, when integrating with my frontend the browser is failing at preflight check. And I know this is due to CORS policy and add the following to my SAM template to configure CORS:

```
Globals:
  HttpApi:
    CorsConfiguration:
      AllowOrigins:
        - http://localhost:3000 # Replace with specific origins if needed
      AllowHeaders:
        - '*'
      AllowMethods:
        - GET
        - POST
        - OPTIONS
      AllowCredentials: true
```

Now during preflight I can see all the Allow-Access* headers as expected:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Max-Age:600
```

However, the preflight request is failing with `401 Unauthorized`

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/timesheets-svc/getEmployee' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I think if I make the call to OPTIONS to return 200 status, then I should be good. But how?

Comment: Where does the 401 status come from? A preflight request is always made without authentification and should never lead to a 401 status.